# Outlook add-in commands VersionOverrides and activation rules not allowed

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins

Anyone know why Microsoft removed rules from VersionOverrides section of manifest file for command add-in

Is there any alternate to show/hide or disable/enable button in ribbon based on content of the email or subject of the email.

Answer (score 0):

The Ribbon commands UI for web add-ins are not dynamic and cannot be changed at run time.  Only desktop (COM) add-ins have this capability using Ribbon Extensibility.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure who is downgrade the question, as it looks to me very much legit. Lets try to answer ...

> Outlook add-in commands VersionOverrides and activation rules not allowed

Yes, the `Rule` tag is not the part of [VersionOverrides schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775495%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> Anyone know why Microsoft removed rules from VersionOverrides section of manifest file for command add-in

Probably this is the question to Microsoft Office JS API team, but the following is the quote from "[Add-in commands for Outlook](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook?product=outlook)" documentation:

> "Add-in commands are only available for contextual add-ins that do not use ItemHasAttachment, ItemHasKnownEntity, or ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch rules to limit the types of items they activate on. However, contextual add-ins can present different commands depending on whether the currently selected item is a message or appointment, and can choose to appear in read or compose scenarios."

To re-phrase this simply indicates that [Activation Rules](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/activation-rules?product=outlook) are out for this type of add-in.

> Is there any alternate to show/hide or disable/enable button in ribbon based on content of the email or subject of the email.

Eric Legault already answered on this question and the answer is No, unfortunately.

If this is the feature you would like to see in upcoming releases, you may want to try to post or up vote the request to https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft pass us the below comments on this
"Command extension points do not support rule activation today. The current solution is to leverage the Detected Entity extension point."